# I am using the Tor browser to post ads on Craigslist, is there a way to post from the US?

Tags: help

So, we are self employed, and use Craigslist to post ads for our business. Every few months Craigslist goes on a rampage, and starts autoflagging accounts for no good reason using IP addresses. Not going to get into all of those details here. Anyhow, we are trying to figure out how to post from the US using Tor, as Craigslist has blacklisted most of the identities we are getting from Tor now. Is there a way to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: No, there is no way to fix this by using Tor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Exitnodes in your torrc to set a country code which will make the traffic look like it's coming from that particular country but it's purely a matter of luck when it comes to getting connected to exit nodes that aren't blacklisted as exit nodes handle several connections at any given time, they'll appear as bots to website so they get blacklisted.